# Shake effect on fixed element when scroll parent fixed element ios

Tags: ios, scroll, css-position, fixed

Start structure of my html

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="parent__content">
        <p>Some text...</p>
        <p>Some text...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Follow this simple example for see the css code: https://codepen.io/SarioDesign/pen/jYZZEb

Only on iOS mobile device, when scroll the '.child' element have a 'shake' effect.

I can't fix that, has anyone had the same problem?